# Strange effect when I scroll in the editor

Tags: block-editor

I've made a simple block that displays a video player in the editor. When I use this block, the editor adopts a strange behavior when scrolling (see video).

https://youtu.be/iwDsVh4GYKE

My guess is that the block rendering updates on scroll and disappears for a very short time. It's possible? Is rendering updated when scrolling? How can it be avoided? What other causes could there be?

This is the code for the block, in the `edit()` function:

```
export default function Edit({ className, attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState("");

    const addVideo = () => {
        setVideo(attributes.videoId);
    };

    const AgVideo = () => {
        return (
            <Player controls>
                <Youtube videoId={video} />
            </Player>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <div>
                <TextControl
                    label="YouTube video ID"
                    help="Algo parecido a: DyTCOwB0DVw"
                    className={className}
                    value={attributes.videoId}
                    onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ videoId: val })}
                />
                <Button isPrimary onClick={addVideo}>
                    Añadir vídeo. añadido: {video}
                </Button>
                <AgVideo />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don’t see anything in your code that would do this, or cause a render on scroll, but you are using a third party component that could have something that scrolls it into view automatically. You’ll need to consult is documentation or ask its author.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clue.